# Adding eCommerce functionality to a MOSS site

Tags: e-commerce

Has anyone had any experience adding eCommerce functionality to a MOSS site? If so how did you go about it?

It seems Commerce Server has some WebParts that can be used but we can't afford the licensing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commerce Server has an out of the box integration with SharePoint, there are standard web parts for all basic functionality in an eCommerce site. There was a very good demo at TechEd where they built a SharePoint / Commerce Server site from scratch in a 1 hour session.

If you use any other eCommerce software with SharePoint you will probably end up building a lot of the UI, or have a site where some pages are SharePoint and some are not.

Even though there are licence costs connected to Commerce Server, you must also take into consideration the value of your time to buld an alternative.

If you are integrating it into your MOSS site your time-to-market will probably be faster with Commerce Server.

A MOSS licence for use on the internet, for users outside your organization is more expensive than a Commerce Server licence.